# date - name id conversion

Tags: java, android

Given (for example):

```
Dog breeds (Name)  | id

Labrador Retriever | A1
German Shepherd    | A2
Golden Retriever   | A3
```

Now the dog breeds are displayed in a list and someone can select one and i have to store the id from the selected dog.

**The question is what is the best way to convert them in each other.**

At the Moment in android i have two string array ressources, store in one the names and in the other the ids and have a method which searches for the name in the "name-array", give me the index and then i can get the id trough the second "id-array", because the id must be in the same index.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a POJO (Plain Old Java Object) with two fields.

```
public class DogBreed {
    private String name;
    private String id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Use custom adapter to show it. Then you don't have to worry about mirroring indices. Just use getter on correct object.

Default adapters usually use toString method. So you can use more generic solutions by overriding toString.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand you right. At App start i load the data and create for every dog breed a POJO, store them in a list and then filter the list.

Comment: Instead of creating two string arrays create an array of objects that has fields you want so you can access values.

Comment: and how to store the pairs for loading - Database...?

Comment: Where are you saving it?